# How do I get attribute name out of XML DOM

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

The problem im having grabbing the attribute names out of xml document. Here is the snippet:

```
<RUNWAY name="02X" length="3507" slope="-0.11" level_off_height="2228">
```

I have created a loop to display the results. In the snippet above, how do i grab the attributes name(name, length, slope, and level_of_height). I have used reader.name is giving me RUNWAY which is correct as the elements name. I tried getAttribute and it give me all of the values of the attributes, but not there name. <strike>Please forgive the (!) as they are open and closed brackets. It would not let me post my question with those in there.</strike> Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: You need to tell us more. What are you using to read the XML with? An `XmlTextReader`? `XDocument`? Post a code sample that you've tried and we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `XmlReader` try [Reading Attributes (from MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by2bd43b.aspx):

```
' Display all attributes.
If reader.HasAttributes Then
  Console.WriteLine("Attributes of <" + reader.Name + ">")
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To (reader.AttributeCount - 1)
    Console.WriteLine("  {0}", reader(i))
  Next i
  ' Move the reader back to the element node.
  reader.MoveToElement() 
End If
```

or another way:

```
If reader.HasAttributes Then
  Console.WriteLine("Attributes of <" + reader.Name + ">")
  While reader.MoveToNextAttribute()
    Console.WriteLine(" {0}={1}", reader.Name, reader.Value)
  End While
  ' Move the reader back to the element node.
  reader.MoveToElement()
End If
```